# Increment GPS coordinates by a certain distance given in meters

Tags: gps, coordinates

Say I have this point:

```
45.1200,10.5000
```

From there I want to create another point that is 20 meters north and 10 meter east from the previous point. Is there any equation I can use for doing this?

Comment: This is one of the most frequently asked questions here at GIS SE.  You can also google the "forward geodetic problem".