# Lat/Lon point transformation/offset on arbitrary segment

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, offset

I'm looking for something very similar to those stack exchange GIS questions: 
[Algorithm for offsetting a latitude/longitude by some amount of meters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/algorithm-for-offsetting-a-latitude-longitude-by-some-amount-of-meters), [How to convert (geodetic pose + cartesian offset) to geodetic position](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81556/how-to-convert-geodetic-pose-cartesian-offset-to-geodetic-position?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Increment GPS coordinates by a certain distance given in meters [duplicate]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166624/increment-gps-coordinates-by-a-certain-distance-given-in-meters?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Quick way to determine if facing a given lat/lon pair with a heading](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/quick-way-to-determine-if-facing-a-given-lat-lon-pair-with-a-heading?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I cannot get my head around to combine them for my specific question:

The most relevant would be the first one, but it refers to a specific vector/heading offset. What I'm looking for is a way to calculate an offset of some meters (less than 200 meters) for a point **A**, on the segment defined by this point **A** and another point **B**, having less than 1km of distance between them.

How can I apply the first answer of SE GIS with a calculation of heading (like the one in the last answer) in order to transpose point **A** for 100 meters in the direction of **B**?

Comment: Unless you're near the poles, for a distance this small, could you assume linearity instead of creating a great circle from A to B? If not, my https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bclib.pl#L3407 does what you want, but is overkill for short distances.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I wouldn't mind having precision even if it's an overkill. To be honest I cannot completely understand your code but I guess it's a version of the one I've finally used : http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html . If you don't mind I'll answer my question by providing the link.

Comment: Don't mind, go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I've managed to find a workaround even though I'm not sure if it makes sense.

By using the information from [*here*](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) I've first calculated the bearing between the two points and then used the result to calculate the *Destination point given distance and bearing from start point*.

Searching a little bit more I've seen that this is a pretty common solution.